# Naming Conventions For iOS Image Resolutions?

Tags: ios, iphone

I know this is a topic that has a plethora of useful information on the web, but there's one piece of the puzzle I can't seem to figure out.

In the app I'm designing, which will support all devices that support iOS 9, I have an image that I want to have take up the whole screen when the device is in landscape.

For the sake of learning, I am trying to use size classes and auto-layout, rather than using code (I've been successful in doing this pragmatically, but I'm trying to figure out this concept).

My images for iPhone are named like so;
image@3x~iphone.png
image@2x~iphone.png
image@2x~ipad.png
image~ipad.png

What I can't seem to figure out is how to work with a device like iPhone 4s, which has a completely different aspect ratio than iPhone 5s, 6, 6 Plus.  When I run my app, the image appears "squished," since the image is designed for a 16:9 screen.  From [this](http://www.vigorouscoding.com/2012/03/naming-conventions-for-image-resources-in-ios/) site, I tried naming an image image-960h@2x~iphone.png, which does not seem to get called when I build the app.

Can anyone advise how you'd work with images @2x resolutions that are going to be shown on devices with different aspect ratios?  Thanks!

Comment: There is no convention or direct support for screen-sized images.

Comment: As maddy says, there's no direct support, but you can sometimes choose auto layout options that have a reasonable behaviour if the image is larger than the screen. For example, if you set an aspect ratio constraint, then the image won't look squished, but may be cropped on smaller devices. That avoids the "squish" effect.

Comment: Understood.  I've started toying with `Aspect Fit` and `Aspect Fill` in interface builder, and have found some success with my results.  Thank you for the replies and sorry for wasting everyone's time!